# php boolean inside loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, boolean

so i have these code..

```
function closest(array $numbers, $nearest = 1) {
  $max = PHP_INT_MAX;
  foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $distance = abs($number - $nearest);
    if($distance < $max) {
      $max = $distance;
      $nearest = $number;
    }
  }
  return $nearest;
}
```

i wanna put the "closest" into:

```
$result_id[][] = "";
    $result_total[][] = "";
    foreach ($user as $key) {
        $a = 0;
        foreach ($drama as $row) {
            if (closest($w_average[$key['userid']][$row['id']] > 0)) {
                
                if ($a < 5) {
                     $result_id[$key['userid']][$a] = $row['id'];
                     $result_total[$key['userid']][$a] = $w_average[$key['userid']][$row['id']];
                    $a++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but the output said

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to closest() must be of the type array, bool given and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\drakor-web3\rekomendasi.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\drakor-web3\rekomendasi.php(129): closest(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\drakor-web3\rekomendasi.php on line 7

the w_average type is
@var (int|float)[][]|int[][] $w_average

thank you

Comment: You are passing `$w_average[$key['userid']][$row['id']] > 0` as the first parameter which is a Boolean

Comment: how to put the closest function into w_average? @ChrisHaas

Comment: My _guess_ is that you want `if(closest($w_average[$key['userid']][$row['id']]) > 0)`

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes, but the w_average is a boolean and the function closest is an array

Comment: The variable `$w_average` appears to be an array based on how you are using it. It might _hold_ booleans, but if you use brackets that implies array

Comment: I already answer your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481109/php-get-the-nearest-value-to-1/70481471?noredirect=1#comment124599138_70481471 but think about it that first arguments is an array you may store it to the array and pass into the closest function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.